# PHP contact form not getting all information from another php file

Tags: php

I created a simple contact form where variable $result output is not appearing above that form when the form is submitted. Please help me out.This contact form works fine in the same php file but when I try with another php file(in my case,fetch.php),variable $result in h4 tag of index.php shows no output after submitting form.

```
index.php 
    <?php
    include 'fetch.php';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>PHPMailer Contact Form</title>
            <style>
                label{
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h4> <?php echo $result; ?> </h4>  <!-- here is the problem -->
            <form method="post" action="fetch.php">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email"><br>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">  
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>

fetch.php
    <?php
     /* 
      * To change this license header, choose License Headers in 
        Project Properties.
      * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
      * and open the template in the editor.
      */
    //These lines must be at the top script
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    $result="";       // this is the variable i asked about
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $uname=$_POST['name'];
        $uemail=$_POST['email'];
        $usub=$_POST['subject'];
        $umsg=$_POST['message'];
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';             //composer's autoloader
        $mail = new PHPMailer;                     //creat object                                 

        //Server settings
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';            //SMTP server                                          
        $mail->isSMTP();                           //set mailer to use smtp                                   
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                    //enable authentication                               
        $mail->Username = 'my@gmail.com';          //smtp user name                         
        $mail->Password = 'secrete';               // smtp password                
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 //Enable TLS encryption                                
        $mail->Port = 587;                         //Tcp port to connect                                  
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                      //Set email format to HTML                                         
        $mail->Subject = 'From Form :'.$usub;   //subject                                     
        $mail->Body= '<h3>'                                                          
                .'Name :'.$uname
                .'<br>E-mail :'.$uemail
                .'<br>Message :'.$umsg
                . '</h3>';`enter code here`          
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($uemail,$uname);                                             
        $mail->addAddress('my@gmail.com', 'to  User');             
        $mail->addReplyTo($uemail,$uname);

        if(!$mail->send())       //send mail                                                    
        {
            $result = "Message could not be sent.";
        }   
        else 
        {
            $result ="Thank you ".$uname." for contacting us.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: mmh, the `action="fetch.php"` seems weird, when, after posting, it should display a message ... meaning, the index.php isn't executed at all, thus, no form, no h4, nothing... maybe you meant to move the h4 into the fetch.php?

Comment: Thank's for trying to help.My question was no output is appearing in display after submitting form.

Comment: I know what your question was. I already answered your question. When the form has an attribute "action" (this is where the form data is sent) and that is set to a script that doesn't produce any output, you get no output. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: oh,well,yea.You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options,

**1. Use sessions**

In fetch.php put this code at the end

```
$ _SESSION['result'] = $result ;
```

And then you can access

```
$_SESSION['result'];
```

in index.php

In order to initialize sessions put

```
session_start();
```

at the top of both files.

**2. Url parameter**

In fetch.php add this at the end

```
header('Location: index.php?result='.$result);
```

Then you can access this url parameter in index.php as follows,

```
$_GET['result'];
```

index.php

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PHPMailer Contact Form</title>
        <style>
            label{
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4> <?php if(isset($_SESSION['result'])){ echo $_SESSION['result']; $_SESSION['result']=''; } ?> </h4>  <!-- here is the problem -->
        <form method="post" action="fetch.php">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email"><br>
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">  
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
 /* 
  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in 
    Project Properties.
  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
//These lines must be at the top script
if(!session_id()) session_start();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$result="";       // this is the variable i asked about
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $uname=$_POST['name'];
    $uemail=$_POST['email'];
    $usub=$_POST['subject'];
    $umsg=$_POST['message'];
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';             //composer's autoloader
    $mail = new PHPMailer;                     //creat object                                 

    //Server settings
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';            //SMTP server                                          
    $mail->isSMTP();                           //set mailer to use smtp                                   
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                    //enable authentication                               
    $mail->Username = 'my@gmail.com';          //smtp user name                         
    $mail->Password = 'secrete';               // smtp password                
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 //Enable TLS encryption                                
    $mail->Port = 587;                         //Tcp port to connect                                  
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                      //Set email format to HTML                                         
    $mail->Subject = 'From Form :'.$usub;   //subject                                     
    $mail->Body= '<h3>'                                                          
            .'Name :'.$uname
            .'<br>E-mail :'.$uemail
            .'<br>Message :'.$umsg
            . '</h3>';`enter code here`          
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($uemail,$uname);                                             
    $mail->addAddress('my@gmail.com', 'to  User');             
    $mail->addReplyTo($uemail,$uname);

    if(!$mail->send())       //send mail                                                    
    {
        $result = "Message could not be sent.";
    }   
    else 
    {
        $result ="Thank you ".$uname." for contacting us.";
    }
    $_SESSION['result'] = $result;
}
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help ,but my problem has yet to solve and I would be glad if you can edit my code.

Comment: I modified your code to use sessions, check if it works now.

Comment: Can't make it.Now two problems come out. The first one is $result value is appearing before submitting form and second one is after submitting form,I got  an error message that says "Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpMailer5\fetch.php on line 11 ".

Comment: You are seeing those errors because you did not remove the line=>  include 'fetch.php'; from index.php, Remove that line, and also I added a condition now on the session_start(), see my edited code.

Comment: Now it works fine.You are amazing and  I am eternally grateful for all you have done.

Comment: Yw, glad I could help